# How can I implement PersistedGrantStore on my mongodb database

Tags: c#, identityserver4, asp.net-core-1.1

I am trying to implement PersistedGrantStore on mongodb, I have managed successfully to use mongodb to store users and client and now I am trying to store grants instead of using in memory grant stores
I created a class which inherits from IPersistedGrantStore

```
public class PersistedGrantStore : IPersistedGrantStore
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<PersistedGrant>> GetAllAsync(string subjectId)
    {
        PersistedGrantService persistedGrantService = new PersistedGrantService();
        return await persistedGrantService.GetAllPersistedGrant(subjectId);
    }

    public async Task<PersistedGrant> GetAsync(string key)
    {
        PersistedGrantService persistedGrantService = new PersistedGrantService();
        return await persistedGrantService.GetPersistedGrantByKey(key);
    }

    public async Task RemoveAllAsync(string subjectId, string clientId)
    {
        PersistedGrantService persistedGrantService = new PersistedGrantService();
        await persistedGrantService.RemoveAllBySubjectIdAndClientId(subjectId, clientId);
    }

    public async Task RemoveAllAsync(string subjectId, string clientId, string type)
    {
        PersistedGrantService persistedGrantService = new PersistedGrantService();
        await persistedGrantService.RemoveAllBySubjectIdAndClientIdAndType(subjectId, clientId, type);
    }

    public async Task RemoveAsync(string key)
    {
        PersistedGrantService persistedGrantService = new PersistedGrantService();
        await persistedGrantService.RemoveAllByKey(key);
    }

    public async Task StoreAsync(PersistedGrant grant)
    {
        PersistedGrantService persistedGrantService = new PersistedGrantService();
        await persistedGrantService.InsertPersistedGrant(grant);
    }
}
```

And in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddSigningCredential(cert)
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityConfiguration.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(ApiResourceConfiguration.GetApiResources());

        builder.Services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IClientStore, ClientStore>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IPersistedGrantStore, PersistedGrantStore>();
    }
```

It seems whatever I do none of the functions in PersistedGrantStore is called, I am not sure what I a missing here, still I can ping the server and get access token so I am assuming inmemory storage is still being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I didn't hit a case where the application needed to store the grant types, which are using code/hybrid flow, reference tokens, or prompting for consent.
When I added AllowOfflineAccess = true to the client I can see the collection is created on the DB
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/699