# How can I implement PersistedGrantStore on a mongodb database?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver4

I am trying to implement PersistedGrantStore on mongodb. I have seen similar questions and answers but no luck so far ([How can I implement PersistedGrantStore on my mongodb database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658600/how-can-i-implement-persistedgrantstore-on-my-mongodb-database)).

I have created a class inhertied from IPersistedGrantStore I have inject it in DI using AddTransient, but still no call is made within my class. Here is a section of my code within ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) function of startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.Authority = authorityServerURL;// "https://demo.identityserver.io";                    
                                                   //options.ApiName = "BWalle_API";
                                                   //options.ApiSecret = "Odsdffegfgdfgdfglq_";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.EnableCaching = false;                
            options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Jwt;
        });

var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {              
            options.Endpoints.EnableUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.Events = new EventsOptions()
            {
                RaiseErrorEvents = true,
                RaiseFailureEvents = true,
                RaiseInformationEvents = true,
                RaiseSuccessEvents = true
            };
        })
            .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
            .AddSigningCredential(new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(GetSecurityKey(), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha512Signature))                 
            .AddResourceStore<ResourceStore>()
            .AddClientStore<ClientStore>()                
            .AddProfileService<MongoDbProfileService>()
            .AddResourceOwnerValidator<MongoDbResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>()
            .AddJwtBearerClientAuthentication();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IPersistedGrantStore, PersistedGrantStore>();
```

And this is the ClientStore Class:

```
public class ClientStore : IClientStore
{
    Task<Client> IClientStore.FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId)
    {
        Client client = new Client
        {
            ClientId = "BWalle_API",
            ClientName = "BWalle API Client",
            //AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            //AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,                
            AllowedGrantTypes = new List<string>() {
                        GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                        GrantType.Hybrid,
                        GrantType.ClientCredentials                            
                    },
            ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                    {
                        new Secret("Odsdffegfgdfgdfglq_".Sha512())
                    },

            AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                        IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Phone,
                        "BWalle_API"
                    },
            Enabled = true,
            //AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
            //{
            //    "http://localhost:4200"
            //},                
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            AllowRememberConsent = false,                
            AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
            IdentityTokenLifetime = 3600 * 24, // Lifetime to identity token in seconds (defaults to 300 seconds / 5 minutes)
            AccessTokenLifetime = 3600 * 24, //3600, // Lifetime of access token in seconds (defaults to 3600 seconds / 1 hour)
            AuthorizationCodeLifetime = 3600 * 24, // Lifetime of authorization code in seconds (defaults to 300 seconds / 5 minutes)
            RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
            RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
            UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
            IncludeJwtId = true
        };

        return Task.FromResult<Client>(client);
    }
}
```

And this is the PersistedGrantStore Class:

```
public class PersistedGrantStore : IPersistedGrantStore
{
    private readonly IAppRepository appRepository;

    public PersistedGrantStore(IAppRepository DBAppRepository)
    {
        this.appRepository = DBAppRepository;
    }


    public Task<IEnumerable<PersistedGrant>> GetAllAsync(string subjectId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<PersistedGrant> GetAsync(string key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();            

    }

    public Task RemoveAllAsync(string subjectId, string clientId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();            
    }

    public Task RemoveAllAsync(string subjectId, string clientId, string type)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();            
    }

    public Task RemoveAsync(string key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();            
    }

    public Task StoreAsync(PersistedGrant grant)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();            
    }
}
```

I am using those nuget packages:

Identityserver4\2.1.3,

Identityserver4.AccessTokenValidation\2.5.0

Contrib.Microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.mongodb\2.0.5

I have managed successfully to use mongodb to store users and client and now I am trying to store grants instead of using in memory grant stores but no call is made whith in PersistedGrantStore class.

I am using ResourceOwner as GrantType (JWT - Bearer Model).

I can not see what I am missing, any help would be realy helpfull!!!

Answer (score 1):

Solved!!!! What was missing was adding to the scope the 'offline_access' when sending from client to the server the connection request to the endpoint '/connect/token'.

Example of post '/connect/token' with data in body :

client_id=BWalle_API&client_secret=mysecretAPlq_&grant_type=password&scope=BWalle_API offline_access&username=undefined&password=undefined&rememberme=&VerCode=1820-0327-2104-0012